# Using Android Studio's diff and merge via CLI with opened instance

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Android Studio lets you perform diff and merge b/w files via CLI using the studio command. Like:

```
/usr/local/bin/studio diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you execute the above command without having any Studio instances open already, it'll start one and show the diff view in it.

If you execute it with a Studio instance already open, then it says "**No IDE instance has been found. New one will be started.**", returns focus to Studio, but does nothing! (no diff view)

(I want this functionality to be able to use studio command as git diff/mergetool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try recreating the command-line launcher using *Tools - Create Command-line Launcher...*

Usually, such issues happen when an older launcher is used with newer IDE version.

Comment: Worked! Overwrote the old `/usr/local/bin/studio` with new one.